# Deploy PHP website on Heroku

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I have got heroku up and running just now. Not sure how to use the PostgreSQL and how to deploy my website though. It is a few php files. But they php files don't open they are just blank so I guess it is never leaving the index.php

Do i need to include or list all my php files in the default index.php file?

Also with the database i created one and it is in the dashboard listed under apps so now can I connect to it normally or is there more stuff to configure?

Would love some video tutorials showing how to deploy small database driven websites written in PHP to heroku.

Any help is great! Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use **postgresql** database with your website on Heroku, you need [this add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql). To set it up read this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql post.

As for PHP, you seem new to it. To include a file you need to use either [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

You can look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLTevnSO53A), for basic deployment of PHP on Heroku.

Comment: With the database I done everything upto 'Establish primary DB' section. Is that all thats needed?